# MsBuild.exe doesn't recognize the outputpath

Tags: msbuild

I specified the OutputPath for MsBuild.exe but it doesn't recognize.Build Succeeded but there are no files in `c:/TEST` folder. Could you please let me know if I am missing something? Where does the release files store by default?

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>MsBuild.exe "c:\TFS\WebApps.sln" /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=c:\TEST`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using OutDir instead of OutputPath? This is a comment from the Microsoft.Common.targets file:

> ```
> OutDir:
> Indicates the final output location for the project or solution. When building a solution,
> OutDir can be used to gather multiple project outputs in one location. In addition,
> OutDir is included in AssemblySearchPaths used for resolving references.
>
> OutputPath:
> This property is usually specified in the project file and is used to initialize OutDir.
> OutDir and OutputPath are distinguished for legacy reasons, and OutDir should be used if at all possible.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing that command under c:\TFS?

My guess is to look at the console output to find out where it's placing files under C:\TFS first.

Then try including this in your command:

```
/fl3 /flp3:Verbosity=diag;logfile=msbuild.log
```

Then open the log in your favorite text editor and investigate away!